# Touchpad moves way too fast

Tags: touchpad

I recently put Ubuntu on my MSI U120. When I use my touchpad though, it is way too sensitive and the pointer moves super fast. I went to the place where you can change the sensitivity in the dash but it was already to as "slow" as it could go. So I did some research and found that this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install gsynaptics
gpointing-device-settings
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is not really clear, what your question actually is. Do you have a problem with your touchpad? Did you find a solution by yourself? Please edit your post to make this clear, there is an `edit` link right below your post. If you've found an answer, then enter the answer in the box labeled `Your Answer` below your post. After one day or so your will be able to accept your own solution so that the question can be considered solved.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the errors I had. I don't really know what I am doing, but am learning. Did my edit make the question clearer? 
Yes, I did find the answer by searching on the internet, but it was from a different forum so I wanted to share it here, but wasn't sure what the proper way was.
I will make sure to add the solution to the answer box you told me about, but I don't know how to make it look nice like you did.

Comment: Right on the upper right corner of the box is a question mark symbol. Click it, and more help will be shown. You can also go to edit mode of your quetion and look how markup is done there.

Comment: Bender: I think I figured out how to write it correctly in the answer. Did I do it right?

Comment: Almost. Try 4 white spaces in front of each of the commands, this is more appropriate for terminal entries than the markup you used.

Comment: I don't even know what "markup" means :) But, I think I did it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7118/discussion-between-user122099-and-bender)

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by entering these two lines and then adjusting the sensitivity.

> > sudo apt-get install gsynaptics
> >       gpointing-device-settings

Comment: For me this works until reboot, after reboot the touchpad is too fast again.

Comment: `gsynaptics` is not shipped with ubuntu anymore, and I'm not sure where it should be installed from

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal
Run the command: xinput --list --short and note the name of your device.
Set the constant deceleration for the device:

xinput --set-prop "Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 5
That's it. You might have to play around with the value, 5 is good for me.

To see the current settings for the device:

xinput --list-props "Razer DeathAdder"

[[http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/][1]](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/%5d%5b1%5d)

On my Acer Aspire 5250 I have an ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad which was happier at 7

xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 7